# Does spacemacs allow toggling cross-air/vertical cursor bar?

Tags: spacemacs

Does `spacemacs` provide an option to enable vertical cursors bars? I'm interested in enabling such a mode together with default horizontal cursor bar highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any nice out-of-the-box solutions. You could start here to set this up, although ideally this would be submitted to MELPA:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CrosshairHighlighting

Or you can use the built-in `highlight-indentation-current-column-mode` to add vertical highlighting to the indentation level of the line you are on. To change the face, use:

`(set-face-background 'highlight-indentation-current-column-face "#4e4e4e") ;; insert color of choice`